# Gulp task not working?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

Hey so I have a gulp task to minify my html files but it is not working.

gulpfile.js contents:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-html-minifier');



gulp.task('autoprefixer', function () {
    return gulp.src('assets/css/*.css')
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../../dist/css/'));
});

gulp.task('minify-html', function() {
  gulp.src('*.html')
    .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
});
```

Output:

C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Zoid Studios\node_modules\map-stream\index.js:103                                                         throw err                                                                                                               ^                                                                                                                Error: Parse Error:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  Zoid Studios - Web Agency                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    at new HTMLParser (C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Zoid Studios\node_modules\gulp-html-minifier\node_modules\html-minifier\src\htmlparser.js:236:13)
                                                                                                    at minify (C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Zoid Studios\node_modules\gulp-html-minifier\node_modules\html-minifier\src\htmlminifier.js:861:3) 
                                                                                                            at Object.exports.minify (C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Zoid Studios\node_modules\gulp-html-minifier\node_modules\html-minifier\src\htmlminifier.js:1216:10) 
                                                                                           at C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Zoid Studios\node_modules\gulp-html-minifier\index.js:51:40

at wrappedMapper (C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Zoid Studios\node_modules\map-stream\index.js:84:19)

at Stream.stream.write (C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Zoid Studios\node_modules\map-stream\index.js:96:21)

at write (C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Zoid Studios\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:623:24)
                                                                                                                 at flow (C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Zoid Studios\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:632:7)
                                                                                                                   at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable (C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Zoid Studios\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\readable-stream\lib_stream_readable.js:664:5) 
                                                                                   at emitNone (events.js:67:13)                                                                                                                                                                                                               C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\Zoid Studios>

I use the "gulp minify-html" command in the npm cmd prompt.

Any help?

Comment: Are you sure that you have added the gulp-html-minified task with "npm install gulp-html-minifier
"?

Comment: What do you mean? I have it installed and have the task js in the gulpfile.js file.

Comment: I re-ran npm install gulp-html-minifier" and it is still not working. @da1lbi3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My project is working with this code. Note that the task is watching my src folder at the root. And the output is written to the dist folder in my root.

I have installed the watch plugin with: `npm install --save-dev gulp-watch` and html min with: `npm i gulp-htmlmin --save-dev`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('default', ['watch','minify']);

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('src/*.html', ['minify']);
});

gulp.task('minify', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/*.html')
    .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

Comment: The output is in the OP @da1lbi3

Comment: Did this and I still got the same error output. @da1lbi3

Comment: @Zoid Okay, im going to setup a local test environment and i will let you know if it works.

Comment: @Zoid are you using an templating engine?

Comment: No I am not @da1lbi3

Comment: Still getting nowhere @da1lbi3

Comment: Will I upload my files so you can have the same files as I do? @da1bi3

Comment: @Zoid Okay, no problem.

Comment: @zoid Remove the <! DOCTYPE html> at your html file. That should do the trick.

Comment: Turned out I was using the wrong html file xD @da1lbi3 Thanks four the help!